# R vectorization and dplyr mutate bug?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a simple function to calculate a vectorised sum (in this example I'm using a [powersum](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html) but my actual use is a more complex function) and a `data.frame` to calculate it over.

`mapply` works just fine to do so, but `dplyr::mutate` is throwing the warning message: `Warning message: In 1:n : numerical expression has 4 elements: only the first used`. If I use `rowwise` first `mutate` gives me the correct result.

I'd appreciate some insight into what is going on.

```
powersum <- function(n, p) {
  i <- 1:n # this is the basic structure that I am using
  sum(i^p) # `i^p` is more complex in my real function with more variables
}

df <- data.frame(
  n = c(1:4),
  p = rep(3, 4)
)

mapply(powersum, df$n, df$p) # works great

library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(powersum = powersum(n, p)) # throws warning about elements

df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(powersum = powersum(n, p)) # works, but why?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need the corresponding option in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
   mutate(powersum = map2_dbl(n, p, powersum))
#   n p powersum
#1 1 3        1
#2 2 3        9
#3 3 3       36
#4 4 3      100
```

---

The `rowwise` works as it is grouping by row, thus it takes each element at a time and applying the function.  Same concept as in the loop with `mapply` where the function is applied on each of the elements.  `powersum` is not vectorized as the sequence `1:n` is not vectorized.  As an example

```
n1 <- 1:2
1:n1
[1] 1
```

> Warning message:
>       In 1:n1 : numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used

The `mutate` case is similar to applying the function using

```
with(df, powerset(n, p))
```

or `transform`

```
transform(df, powersum = powerset(n, p))
```

Both are applying the function on the entire row for each column

Comment: Thank you. I was able to use `Vectorize` on my function. I appreciate this explanation.

Comment: @LiefEsbenshade `Vectorize` is doing `lapply` i.e. a loop

Comment: Right. Maybe this comment string isn't the right place to ask, but I have several functions to implement that involve summing from 1:n, is there a more efficient set up to use than what I show above?

Comment: @LiefEsbenshade You could use `sequence` i.e. `sequence(3, 4)`, but that also depends on the other functions as the length is now 7 instead of 2, which would make it difficult or else have to do some processiing into a list or so.